# How do I refresh WatchApp complications

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

So I'm trying to update `headerTextProvider:` every second with a `Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in`

I guess that this is not the right way of doing this?

```swift
    // MY STUFF HERE
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication,
                                 withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {

        @ObservedObject var service = Service()
        print("-------------------->>>>>>>>>> \(service.currentTime)")
        let date = Date()
        //let currentTime = service.currentTime
        let title = service.title
        let time = service.time

        var template: CLKComplicationTemplate!
        let line1 = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text:title)
        let line2 = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text:time)
        //let line3 = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text:currentTime)

        if complication.family == .modularLarge {
            template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody(headerTextProvider: line1, body1TextProvider: line2)
            let entry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: date, complicationTemplate: template)
            handler(entry)
        }
        else{
            handler(nil)
        }
    }
```

## The Whole Code

```swift
//
//  ComplicationController.swift
//  WatchApp WatchKit Extension
//
//  Created by Mathias Halén on 2021-06-22.
//  Copyright © 2021 Mathias Halén. All rights reserved.
//

import ClockKit
import SwiftUI


class ComplicationController: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource {
    final class Service: ObservableObject{
        static let sharedInstance1 = Service()
        @Published var currentTime = " first time"
        @Published var title = "Hello"
        @Published var time = "World"
        
        init() {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
                print("----------> WatchOS -> ComplicationController \(Date())")
                self.currentTime = GlobalVaribles.sharedInstance.currentTime
                self.title = GlobalVaribles.sharedInstance.title
                self.time = GlobalVaribles.sharedInstance.time
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Complication Configuration
    func getComplicationDescriptors(handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationDescriptor]) -> Void) {
        
        let descriptors = [
            CLKComplicationDescriptor(identifier: "complication",
                                      displayName: "Test 2",
                                      supportedFamilies: CLKComplicationFamily.allCases)
            // Multiple complication support can be added here with more descriptors
        ]
        
        // Call the handler with the currently supported complication descriptors
        handler(descriptors)
    }
    func handleSharedComplicationDescriptors(_ complicationDescriptors: [CLKComplicationDescriptor]) {
        // Do any necessary work to support these newly shared complication descriptors
    }
    // MARK: - Timeline Configuration
    func getTimelineEndDate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with the last entry date you can currently provide or nil if you can't support future timelines
        let currentDate = Date()
        handler(currentDate)
    }
    func getPrivacyBehavior(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationPrivacyBehavior) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with your desired behavior when the device is locked
        handler(.showOnLockScreen)
    }
    func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
        // This method will be called once per supported complication, and the results will be cached
        handler(nil)
    }
    // MY STUFF HERE
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication,
                                 withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
        
        @ObservedObject var service = Service()
        print("-------------------->>>>>>>>>> \(service.currentTime)")
        let date = Date()
        //let currentTime = service.currentTime
        let title = service.title
        let time = service.time
        
        var template: CLKComplicationTemplate!
        let line1 = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text:title)
        let line2 = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text:time)
        //let line3 = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text:currentTime)
        
        if complication.family == .modularLarge {
            template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody(headerTextProvider: line1, body1TextProvider: line2)
            let entry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: date, complicationTemplate: template)
            handler(entry)
        }
        else{
            handler(nil)
        }
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, you don't "push" timeline entries to your complication.  You supply timeline entries when ClockKit requests them.

You can use [`reloadTimeline`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clkcomplicationserver/1627891-reloadtimeline) and [`extendTimeline`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clkcomplicationserver/1627895-extendtimeline) to trigger a request from ClockKit, but you would normally only use this periodically; Say when user interaction causes your app to load new data or perhaps based on a scheduled refresh task.

See [Keeping Your Complications Up to Date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/keeping_your_complications_up_to_date) for more details.

Using a `Timer` isn't really an approach that makes sense; The `Timer` will only fire when your watch app is in the foreground, and if it is in the foreground then your complication isn't being show.

What you can do is implement `getTimelineEndDate` and `getTimelineEntries` in your data source; then when your data source is asked for entries you can supply future entries for the complication to show.

First, supply `.distantFuture` for the end date, indicating that your complication can provide data indefinitely.

```
func getTimelineEndDate(for complication: CLKComplication, 
                     withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {
    handler(.distantFuture)
}
```

Second, supply a series of time line entries, one for each of the next 3600 seconds, say.

```
func getTimelineEntries(for complication: CLKComplication, 
                           after date: Date, 
                           limit: Int, 
                     withHandler handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void) {

    guard complication.family == .modularLarge else {
        handler(nil)
        return
    }

    let now = Date()
    var entries = [CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]()
    let line1 = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text:title)
    for i in 0..<3600 {
        let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody(headerTextProvider: line1, body1TextProvider: line2)
        let line2 = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text:"\(i)")
        let entry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: date.addingTimeInterval(Double(i)), complicationTemplate: template)
            entries.append(entry)
    }
    completion(entries)
}
```

Comment: You should not provide more entires from getTimelineEntries than is specified by limit. In this case the for loop should probably be limited like so: `for i in 0..<limit`